# How to set black background in input which is in the table when the mouseover to tr?

Tags: javascript

A half of source I've tried to make by myself, but I can't go further, seems I stuck:

```html
<table id="percab" onmouseover="hov();" border="1" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr><td><input type="text" value="something" name="test" /></td><td>welcome</td></tr>
    <tr><Td>check this out</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" value="example" name="sample" /></td><td>sample</td></tr>
</table>​
```

```js
function hov() {
    if(!document.getElementsByTagName || !document.createTextNode) return;
    var rows = document.getElementById('percab').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i].onmouseover = function() {
            for(var childItem in this.childNodes) {
                if(this.childNodes[childItem].nodeType == 1) {
                    this.childNodes[childItem].style.backgroundColor = "#000";
                    this.childNodes[childItem].style.color = "#FFF";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}​
```

If the row has any input (now it's only a text inputs inside) I want to set a backgrounds of this inputs also black.

Please, **pure JavaScript**.

Comment: Please, **indent your code**.

Comment: Which browsers don't support `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: Don't use `for in` loop.

Comment: Or to be more exact, don't use `for..in` to iterate over an array or array-like object. It iterates over *properties* so that's what you should use it for. When iterating over something array-like use `for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)`. Your code is also leaking a global `i` since you did not use `var i`

Comment: I agree with @TheScrumMeister that this kind of check is not necessary anymore nowadays. While I'm pretty sure that it *is* necessary when supporting *extremely* old browsers such as NS4 or IE5.0 I highly doubt that anyone still *needs* to support them (or wants to since it would also mean to write probably much different HTML for them)

Comment: Why JS? That would be so easy with CSS...  `tr :hover input { background-color: #000; color: #fff} `

Comment: @Andreas. Because it's the weekend and in the weekends you don't use CSS, only JS.

Comment: Andreas absolutely right. Thank you, I forgot about this feature of css selection.

Comment: and sorry if I trouble, but is there a way to unfocus active input?

Comment: @AquaVita Yeah, you have to use JS thouugh: `inputElement.blur();`